# Changing PMOS appearance in CircuiTikZ

Tags: circuitikz

I am drawing an electronic circuit plenty of PMOS transistors. It also has nodes in which two paths intersect that I mark with filled circles. The problem is that I am using *to[Tpmos]* for drawing transistors and the filled circle in the gate looks exactly equal than those node filled circles.

How can I change the appearance of PMOS transistors so that the gate filled circle appears as a blank circle?

That's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=600}]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\standaloneenv{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american currents]
    \draw 
    (0,0) to[Tpmos, n=mp1] (0,2)
    (0,2) to[short] (1,2)
    (mp1.gate) to[short] ++(0,1) to [short, -*] ++(1,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

The thing is that I want the PMOS gate to look different from the nodes. Maybe by filling the black circle of the PMOS gate in white instead of in black.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Could you provide a (possibly simplified) example of the code you are using, a screenshot of how it looks now, and a drawing of how you want it to look?

Comment: As per @Marijn comment, it would be nice if you include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Of course, done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of brute force approach. Look into `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/circuitikz/pgfcirctripoles.tex`, copy and modify the thing where it draws the circle and the leading wire:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=600}, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\standaloneenv{circuitikz}
\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclaremos{pmos}{
          \anchor{S}{
            \northeast
          }
          \anchor{source}{
            \northeast
          }
          \anchor{D}{
            \northeast
            \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
          }
          \anchor{drain}{
            \northeast
            \pgf@y=-\pgf@y
          }
}{%
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@up}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate height}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/base width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate height}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
            \pgfusepath{draw}

        \ifpgf@circuit@mos@arrows
            \pgfscope             
            \pgfslopedattimetrue 
            \pgfallowupsidedownattimetrue
            \pgfresetnontranslationattimefalse
            \pgftransformlineattime{.4}{%
                \pgfpoint%
                    {\pgf@circ@res@right}%
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate height}\pgf@circ@res@up}%
            }{%
                \pgfpoint
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate width}\pgf@circ@res@left}%
                    {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate height}\pgf@circ@res@up}%
            }
            \pgfnode{currarrow}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{stroke}}
            \endpgfscope
        \fi

            \pgfscope
            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/base width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/base height}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/base width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/base height}\pgf@circ@res@down}}
            \pgfsetlinewidth{2\pgflinewidth}
            \pgfusepath{draw}
            \endpgfscope

            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/base width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate height}\pgf@circ@res@down}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate height}\pgf@circ@res@down}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{\pgf@circ@res@down}}      

            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate height}\pgf@circ@res@up}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate height}\pgf@circ@res@down}}


            \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint %%% changed here to shorten the lead not to cross the circle
                            {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate width}\pgf@circ@res@left-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/nodes width}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}}
                {\pgf@circ@res@up+\pgf@circ@res@down}}
            \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{\pgf@circ@res@up+\pgf@circ@res@down}}
            \pgfusepath{draw}

            \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint
                {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate width}\pgf@circ@res@left - \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/nodes width}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}}
                {\pgf@circ@res@up+\pgf@circ@res@down}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/nodes width}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}}
                        % removed the fill here 
            \pgfusepath{draw, }     
\makeatother
}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american currents]
    \draw 
    (0,0) to[Tpmos, n=mp1] (0,2)
    (0,2) to[short] (1,2)
    (mp1.gate) to[short] ++(0,1) to [short, -*] ++(1,0)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Seems a lot of work, but really the modification is small:

```
-           \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint
-               {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate width}\pgf@circ@res@left}
+           \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint %%% changed here to shorten the lead not to cross the circle
+                            {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/tripoles/pmos/gate width}\pgf@circ@res@left-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/nodes width}*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length}}
                {\pgf@circ@res@up+\pgf@circ@res@down}}
```

for the wire and:

```
-           \pgfusepath{draw,fill}      
-
+                        % removed the fill here 
+           \pgfusepath{draw, }
```

for the fill.

Probably it could be made by some nice incantations of patching with `etoolbox`... now that I see it, I really prefer the new version, so maybe just modifying the original file and putting it in your local `texmf` tree will do.

BTW, it seems that the position of the gate pin is not exactly on grid. If you do:

```
\draw 
    (0,0) to[Tpmos, n=mp1] (0,2)
    (0,2) to[short, *-] (1,2)
    (mp1.gate) to[short] ++(0,1)
    to [short] ++(1,0)
    ;
```

You'll get rid of that horrible connection dot not centered on the connection...

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm. I've done a copy of the .tex file and modify it. Perfect! Thank you very much for your solution!

Answer (score 2):

There is now a better solution! Just add

```
\ctikzset{tripoles/pmos style/emptycircle}
```

to your circuitikz environment. Source: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/238#issuecomment-507619630

Comment: Yes, it was formally added in version 0.9.3, in July 2019. Or around there, `git blame` get lost after the big code reorganization...